# ObjectInputStream throws EOFException

Tags: java, file, file-io, filereader, serializable

I'm writing a class to keep track of competition data at a tournament. I want to store this class to a file, so am using an `ObjectInputStream`. The class I am writing implements Serializable. I'm getting an `EOFException`, and none of the solutions I've found on SO and elsewhere actually address this issue.

My file writer is:

```
public void writeToFile(String path) {
    File f = new File(path);
    if(f.exists()) f.delete();

    try {
        OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(path);
        OutputStream bufferOut = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOut);
        ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(bufferOut);

        output.writeObject(this);
    } catch(IOException e) {}
}
```

My file reader is:

```
public static DivisionDataFTC readFromFile(String path) {
    try {
        InputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(path);
        InputStream bufferIn = new BufferedInputStream(fileIn);
        ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream(bufferIn);

        System.out.println(input.read());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(path);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(1==1) throw new Error("Could not read DivisionDataFTC at " + path);
    return null;
}
```

I write the data successfully - I have verified that the file is *not* empty. (Its contents, if relevant, are consistently 7.99kb).

To be clear, the error does not occur on the instantiation of the ObjectOutputStream. This is what makes this question different - the error occurs on the readObject() call. My output is a remarkably long `EOFException`:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2571)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1315)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at java.util.ArrayList.readObject(ArrayList.java:733)
    (...cut out most of this because nobody wants to read it...)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:369)
    at tournamentftc.DivisionDataFTC.readFromFile(DivisionDataFTC.java:297)
    at firstscouting.FIRSTScouting.runGUI(FIRSTScouting.java:82)
    at firstscouting.FIRSTScouting.main(FIRSTScouting.java:101)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Could not read DivisionDataFTC at C:\Users\Noah\Desktop\out.ser
    at tournamentftc.DivisionDataFTC.readFromFile(DivisionDataFTC.java:303)
    at firstscouting.FIRSTScouting.runGUI(FIRSTScouting.java:82)
    at firstscouting.FIRSTScouting.main(FIRSTScouting.java:101)
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. How do I handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should close ObjectOutputStream, try

```
 ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(bufferOut);
 output.writeObject(this);
 output.close();
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to close your output stream, and you also nee to call readObject() not read.